# How to close a form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

My 1st form is frmLeaveRequest.

And My 2nd Form is frmLeaveRequestConfirmation.

There is a button named "Confirm" in 2nd form. I want to close those 2 forms when click on that button.

I tried to accomplish that task by following code.

```
        frmLeaveRequest frm = new frmLeaveRequest() 
        frm.Close();
        this.Close();
```

but it's doesn't work because it creates just a new object and not the same which I want to close.

Please give me a solution to accomplies that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Form 1
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frmForm2 = new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation();
    frmForm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frmForm2_FormClosed);
    frmForm2.Show();

}

private void frmForm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}


//Form 2
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send those forms to the new form constructor as parameters, so you have the references to them and you can close them.

Comment: Can you give me the correct programming code please?

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri look at Pranay Rana example.